# Flutter "flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle /flutter.gradle' as it does not exist

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to run my flutter project, but I have been getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not read script '/dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle /flutter.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

I tried deleting and reinstalling flutter, changed settings.gradle and upgraded flutter, however nothing changed. I started a new flutter app and it worked fine. I checked flutter.gradle is still in that directory. I assume the error might be caused by the space after "gradle", but how do i fix it?

Comment: Please try by updating the Gradle to the latest version.

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede how do i update my gradle

Comment: android -> build.gradle   
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'  you cna update this version to latest

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede mine is ```classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'```

Comment: Yes try with this now

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede same error

Comment: try with 1) flutter clean 2) flutter create . 3) flutter pub get and then run

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede did all of that, and still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I added " " after gradle in the finder and it works fine so far.